Integrals of Products of Polynomials, Gaussian Exponentials and Modified Bessel Functions of the First Kind. How to derive the mean?
While attempting to derive the mean and variance of the Rice Distribution, defined by the following probability density function
$f_X(x) = \dfrac{x}{b^2} \exp{\left(-\dfrac{x^2+a^2}{2b^2}\right)} I_0 \left( \dfrac{ax}{b^2} \right)$
I have encountered the following integrand
$\displaystyle \bar{X} = \mathbf{E}[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} x f_X(x)\ dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^2}{b^2} \exp{\left(-\dfrac{x^2+a^2}{2b^2}\right)} I_0 \left( \dfrac{ax}{b^2} \right) dx$
Any guides how to proceed in reaching this result?
Where $I_0(\cdot)$ is the modified Bessel function of zero-order of the first kind.
If I make a quick substitution of $z = \dfrac{x}{b}$ and $k = \dfrac{a}{b}$, the integral becomes
$\displaystyle \bar{X} = \int_{0}^{\infty} b z^2 \exp{\left(-\dfrac{z^2+k^2}{2}\right)} I_0 \left( k z \right) dz$
I have struggled to find an identity for proving the final formula, given in Appendix F (eq. F-82) of Probability, Random Variables, and Random Signal Principles, Peyton Z. Peebles 4th ed. by
$\displaystyle \bar{X} = b \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} e^{-k^2/4} \left[ \left( 1 + \dfrac{k^2}{2} \right) I_0 \left( \dfrac{k^2}{4} \right) + \dfrac{k^2}{2} I_1 \left( \dfrac{k^2}{4} \right) \right]$

It is known (cf. Gradshtein & Ryzhik, 6.618-4) that
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}tz^2}I_0(kz) \,\mathrm{d}z = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2t}} \exp\left(\frac{k^2}{4t}\right) I_0\left(\frac{k^2}{4t}\right),
$$
hence
$$
\bar{X} = -2be^{-\frac{1}{2}k^2} \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=1} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2t}} \exp\left(\frac{k^2}{4t}\right) I_0\left(\frac{k^2}{4t}\right),
$$
with $I_0' = I_1$. I let you carry the computations from there.

This helped a lot and I was able to compute it easily. Many many thanks to you.

@MohammedSalamaIbrahim  Glad to help ;)
